# Hive SQL + FROM not in to JOIN

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a query with NOT IN clause,need to convert into join statement.

```
SELECT EMP_NBR 
FROM employees not in (select emp_id from departments where dept_id = 10 and division = 'sales')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper transformation would be a `left join`:

```
select EMP_NBR 
from employees e join
     departments d
     on e.dept_id = d.dept_id and 
        d.dept_id = 10 and
        d.division = 'sales'
where d.dept_id is null;
```

Note:  I added what I consider to be correct `JOIN` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

`not in` could be mimicked in SQL using just `not` in the where clause, e.g.

```
SELECT EMP_NBR FROM employees inner join department on
employees.emp_id =departments.emp_id
where NOT (dept_id = 10 and division = 'sales')
```